# Show the most frequent item in a one to many SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-many

Hi All and thanks in advance for any help. This is my scenario:

I have three linked tables showing production specs and type of ink used in each. Each spec can have a variable number of inks (from 1 to 10) which may or may not be the same to the others. My objective is for each spec to be able to show the spec name and the ink that appears more frequently.

For example for spec XYZ:

```
|=====|=====|
¦SPEC ¦INK  ¦
|=====|=====|
¦XYZ  ¦blue ¦
¦XYZ  ¦red  ¦
¦XYZ  ¦red  ¦
¦XYZ  ¦red  ¦
¦XYZ  ¦brown¦
|=====|=====|
```

I would like to display only:

```
|=====|=====|
¦SPEC ¦INK  ¦
|=====|=====|
¦XYZ  ¦red  ¦
|=====|=====|
```

The tables are linked as follows:

```
SELECT tblStudioInput.SpecNo
    , tblListInkSystem.Ink
FROM tblStudioInput
INNER JOIN tblStudioInputColour
    ON tblStudioInput.stID = tblStudioInputColour.StudioInputID
INNER JOIN tblListInkSystem
    ON tblStudioInputColour.InkSystem = tblListInkSystem.ID
```

Again thanks in advance to everybody

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SPEC, INK
FROM
  (
    SELECT SPEC, INK,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY SPEC, INK
  ) s
WHERE rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cd4b/7)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with tie*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69199/9)

SOURCE

- [DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer. I think we are almost there: the query works fine on a one spec at time basis but if I run it for all of them, it only returns 63 specs (out of 5000+) with the relative ink type. I can't identify why those 63 either...

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED] You can try this:

```
select top 1 with ties
    spec, ink
from
    (
      select
          spec, ink, count(*) n
      from
          tmp
      group by
          spec, ink
    ) t
order by
    n desc
```

[UPDATED] [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/303ff/7/0)

Or without sort

```
with q as (
    select
        spec, ink, count(*) n
    from
        tmp
    group by
        spec, ink
)

select
    spec, ink
from
    q
where
    n = (
        select
            max(n)
        from
            q
    )
```

Or without CTE

```
select
    spec, ink
from
    tmp
group by
    spec, ink
having
    count(*) = (
        select
            max(n)
        from
            (
                select
                    count(*) n
                from
                    tmp
                group by
                    spec, ink
            ) t
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Вадим Зинчук. Your query only returns 1 record (1 spec + 1 ink) while what I am trying o achieve is to get all 5000+ specs with the correspondent most frequent ink associated to them.

Comment: Thanks again for your input. Both the queries return only 63 specs (same as John's solution) out of the thousands I'm expecting. As for ties, this is not an issue since all specs will definetely have an ink type that is dominant.

Comment: Please post some test data to debug query

Comment: The query was required in a Crystal report and as it was very urgent I had to sort it out differently within Crystal itself (a bit slow but it does the job). Thanks anyway for your help,  Вадим Зинчук